# how set laravel 5.7 routing

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I generated a controller using `php artisan make:controller BoardController`
but I get a 404 error when I try to reach *localhost/write*.

Does someone know what is problem?

---

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});

Route::get('write', 'BoardController@write');
```

**BoardController**

```
class BoardController extends Controller
{
    public function write()
    {
        return view('write');   
     }
}
```

**write.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    this is write page
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you using Apache/Nginx for serving the app? or **php artisan serve** ? Also,  is the 404 the page one issued by Laravel or the web server?

Comment: As the above comment, what are you using to host the application? nginx, apache? Maybe wamp / xampp ? Your question is missing this information to help with the environment you want to use

Comment: i using apache2 server. and i want use apache, not artisan.

Comment: I have copy laravel/public files in var/www/html.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can run your project in these two ways, these are:

Option 1: **run php artisan serve** command then write url in your browser like 
        http://localhost:8000/ your route name

Option 2 : write url in your browser like 
           **localhost/your project name/your route name**

Comment: Can you please tell me the details problem?